# INSERT happens but upload doesn't

Tags: php, file-upload

```
function Save($name)
    {
        $target_path = "uploads/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'], $target_path)) 
        {
            echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). 
                 " has been uploaded";
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }

        //save
        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        @mysql_select_db('test') or die( "Unable to select database");
        $query = "INSERT INTO test (name)" .
                 "VALUES ('" . $name . "')";
        mysql_query($query);
        mysql_close();
    }
```

So the insert happens but I'm not able to see the .txt file I am uploading into the uploads/ directory. But its inserted into the DB file. Full name of the file.

Why?

Comment: What is the error? `var_dump($_FILES);` and see if it's populated with what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt its because of a permission issue.Did u check whether you have sufficient permission to write to the directory where you are uploading to.Give "Write" access to that directory

Answer (score 0):

Your upload is apparently failing, but the way your function is written, the database insert goes ahead and happens anyway.  For starters, you might want to move that `//save` functionality up into the `if` statement (where the success message is displayed.)  Then, at least you won't be getting the db record without the upload.

As for why the file upload is failing, a good place to start investigating is: the existence of, and permission settings on, that uploads folder.

Comment: Might as well double-check your html form-- single input type=file, correct name, etc? (grasping...)

Comment: I say that because the name you're inserting into the database isn't evidently derived from the actual file name, but rather the function argument, so... could be misleading you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ls -al
chmod 0777 /uploads
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `enctype` of your form?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ...
```

It was a frequent gotcha for me years ago :)